# How to convert GMP C parameter convention into something more natural?

Tags: c, gmp

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
#include <gmp.h>
typedef mpz_t Integer;

// 
Integer F(Integer a,Integer b,Integer c,Integer d) {
    Integer ret = times(plus(a,b),plus(c,d));
}
```

But, GMP doesn't let me do this, apparently mpz_t is an array, so I get the error:

```
error: ‘F’ declared as function returning an array
```

So instead I would have to do something like this:

```
void F(Integer ret,Integer a,Integer b,Integer c,Integer d) {
    Integer tmp1,tmp2;

    plus(tmp1,a,b);     
    plus(tmp2,c,d);     
    times(ret,tmp1,tmp2); 
}
```

This is unnatural, and not following the logical way that C (or in general mathematical) expressions can be composed. In fact, you can't compose anything in a math-like way because apparently you can't return GMP numbers!  If I wanted to write - for example - a simple yacc/bison style parser that converted a simple syntax using +, -, /, * etc. into C code implementing the given expressions using GMP it seems it would be much more difficult as I would have to keep track of all the intermediate values.

So, how can I force GMP to bend to my will here and accept a more reasonable syntax?  Can I safely "cheat" and cast mpz_t to a void * and then reconstitute it at the other end back into mpz_t? I'm assuming from reading the documentation that it is not *really* passing around an array, but merely a reference, so why can't it return a reference as well?   Is there some good sound programming basis for doing it this way that I should consider in writing my own program?

Comment: `typedef Integer mpz_t;` Did you compile this?

Comment: whoops, no, I didn't copy/paste from my source I just manually re-typed and apparently swapped those two around.  I have corrected that mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *gmp.h*:

```
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

This makes a lot of sense, and  *is pretty natural*. Think about it: having an
array of size 1  allows you to deal with an obscured  pointer (known as opaque
reference) and all its advantages:

```
mpz_t number;
DoubleIt(number); /* DoubleIt() operates on `number' (modifies it) as
                     it will be passed as a pointer to the real data */
```

Were it not an array, you'd have to do something like:

```
mpz_t number;
DoubleIt(&number);
```

And then it comes  all the confusion. The intention behind  the opaque type is
to hide  these, so  you don't  have to  worry about  it. And  one of  the main
concerns should  be clear: size  (which leads  to performance). Of  course you
can't return such struct that holds data limited to the available memory. What
about this one (consider `mpz_t` here as a "first-class" type):

```
mpz_t number = ...;
number = DoubleIt(number);
```

You (the program) would have to copy all the data in `number` and push it as a
parameter  to your  function. Then  it needs  to leave  appropriate space  for
returning another number even bigger.

Conclusion: as  you have  to deal  with data  indirectly (with  pointers) it's
better to  use an  opaque type.  You'll be  passing a  reference only  to your
functions,  but  you  can  operate  on  them  as  if  the  whole  concept  was
*pass-by-reference* (C defaults to *pass-by-reference*).

Comment: Ok, I understand why they are using an array of size 1, and it is pretty clever. It also allows you to define local storage a bit more easily than if for example they did typedef __mpz_struct *mpz_t, in which case you would be harder pressed to allocate automatic storage for the underlying struct.  So it is natural from the standpoint of allocating and passing, but not natural from the standpoint of return values.

Comment: And, I guess I should add, this calling convention also allows them to do the trick of detecting when new storage isn't needed, e.g. mpz_add(x,x,x)