# Converting an ull to an mpz_t

Tags: c, gmp

I saw the post at question [mpz_t to unsigned long long conversion (gmp lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248723/mpz-t-to-unsigned-long-long-conversion-gmp-lib) and Chris Jester-Young gave me the answer

```
mpz_t ull2mpz(unsigned long long ull)
{
    char buf[40];
    int len;
    mpz_t result;

    len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%llx");
    if (len >= sizeof buf) { /* oops */ }
    mpz_init(result);
    len = gmp_sscanf(buf, "%Zx", result);
    if (len != 1) { /* oops */ }
    return result;
}
```

The problem here is that, as stated in [How to convert GMP C parameter convention into something more natural?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916401/how-to-convert-gmp-c-parameter-convention-into-something-more-natural) mpz_t is an array. How can I circumvent this(Without doing so strange things, just returning a value)?
If I write instead

```
void mpz_set_ull(mpz_t val, unsigned long long ull){
    char buf[40];
    int len;
    mpz_t result;

    len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%llx");
    if (len >= sizeof buf) { /* oops */ }
    mpz_init(result);
    len = gmp_sscanf(buf, "%Zx", result);
    if (len != 1) { /* oops */ }
    mpz_set(val,result);
}
```

I get wrong results.

And, is his code legal C?

Comment: Uh, you are not even using `ull` in your functions...

Comment: You need to show how you are using those functions. Also, I don't see the point of introducing a result variable (which you forget to free) that you're just going to copy into val.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I just copy-pasted his code and just added the parameter *mpz_t val* the last line to have more control over the problem(less variables).  What is wrong with his code?

Answer (score 0):

OP is not using `snprintf()` correctly.  Need to pass `ull`.

Use

```
char buf[sizeof(ull)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 2];  // let the sizeof `buf` be sized per `ull` needs
...
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%llx", ull);  // Add missing `ull`
```